# What dmidecode Bank Location: PO CHANNEL means?

Tags: ram, dmidecode

When I run command

```
sudo dmidecode -t 17
```

I see :

```
Bank Locator: P0 CHANNEL A
```

1. What this means ?? I searched dmidecode site and docs but not found any information.

I just wanted to check memory mode, but `sudo dmidecode 2.3 | grep Interleaved` only prints:
Interleaved Data Depth: Unknown

2. Is there other way to detect what memory mode is used (8+16 on AMD 4600) ??

Comment: I found an Oracle reference (for Sun Blade X6270) which says "Each processor contains a separate memory controller", and they refer to the multiple paths between CPUs and DIMM memory modules as P0 Channel etc, so it may be common notation. So this may be more associated with your motherboard layout than the specific processor.